# UILocalizedIndexedCollation and non-english indexes

Tags: ios, uitableview, localization

I am using UILocalizedIndexedCollation in my application.
My locale is set to Russian and on indexed table I can see index list with English and Russian indexes. The order is always the same - English alphabet -> Russian alphabet even if I do not have any English values.
Is it possible to place Russian alphabet above English alphabet in index list (like it is done in Contacts app)?

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630184/uilocalizedindexedcollation-for-japanese-giving-different-ordering-to-contacts-m

Answer (score 0):

Check here [UILocalizedIndexedCollation only returns an English collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278960/uilocalizedindexedcollation-only-returns-an-english-collation). Do you have a .lproj? If so make sure you atleast have the folder in the bundle.