# UILocalizedIndexedCollation only returns an English collation

Tags: ios, localization, uikit, collation

I'm trying to get a localized index like Contacts by using `UILocalizedIndexedCollation`. In Contacts when I change the language the index changes to match the language. However `sectionIndexTitles` always returns an english index.

I have tried this with a demo app I created and with `3_SimpleIndexedTableView`, which is a demo app from Apple and neither app have a localized index.

I have tried creating a localization folder for the current locale (I used `[[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale] localeIdentifier]` to determine the current locale). This does not affect the index.

I've had a look for relevant `plist` settings by found nothing.

Am I missing something or does `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` only return an English collation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!

I didn't have a localization folder in my app bundle for the target language. I added `sv.lproj` (Swedish) and the collation worked as expected. The folder is empty, it's presence is all that's required for it to work.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem, but I don't follow your solution. Please elaborate. :-)

Comment: @MdaG An app is considered localized if there's a folder for the localization in the app bundle. Xcode creates the localization folders automatically when a bundle resource (e.g. a nib, image or a .strings file) is localized. (It's possible to manually create these folders within the app bundle too. I created them manually when I was playing with `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` in the simulator).

Comment: Are you saying that if I create sv.lproj in parallel to en.lproj, my app will automatically detect my locale (Swedish) and make sure the section list returns an array containing A - Ö ? (tested it and it doesn't seem to work like that)

If I figure out how it works I'm gonna write a tutorial for n00bs like me. :-)

Comment: @MdaG did u come up with a solution. This one doesnt work for me either :(

Comment: I had forgotten all about this Stack Question. Thanks for reminding me. What I did was localize my application for the relevant languages. I.e. create and localize Localization.strings (using genstrings) in my case, but as far as I see you could just localize an image in your application and the relevant folders that @BenedictCohen mention will be created. You can use the Interface Builder to localize an image view.

Answer (score 8):

You can also set `Localized resources can be mixed = YES` in `Info.plist`.
If the key is missing right click and choose `Add Row`.

Comment: This worked perfect for me. I don't have Swedish localization in my app, but I still generate a localized section header and index based on the data provided by the user.  Now if I could only find a similar UILocalizedIndexedCollation for Mac!